# DOORS DXL issue looping through a filtered dataset

Tags: filter, ibm-doors

I have a script in which I filter the data in a module by a certain attribute value.  When I then loop through these objects, for now, I am displaying the absolute number of the objects in an infoBox.  However, the script is displaying absolute numbers of objects that are not in the dataset.  Upon further investigation, I found that the extra absolute numbers were for each table within the entire module. I can't figure out why the script would include these tables when they are not in the filtered module data.  I have even tried manually filtering the module on this attribute value then use the "Tools -> Edit DXL" to loop through the resulting items and it still displays the numbers for the tables that are not included.  Why would it do this?
Here's my code:

```
bm2 = moduleVar
Filter fltr = contains(attribute "RCR_numbers", sRCRNum, false);
filtering on;
set(bm2, fltr);
for oObj in document(bm2) do {
    absNum = oObj."Absolute Number";
    infoBox("Object #" absNum ".");
}
```

I have also tried removing the document cast so it says "for oObj in bm2 do" instead, but this doesn't change the output.  Why is the code giving me objects that are not in the filter?  Any help would be greatly appreciated since this is a high priority issue for my project and I'm out of ideas myself.

Chris

Comment: If you just run the first four lines of code (i.e., just set the filter, but don't do the counting), do you see the set of objects you expect?

Comment: Yes, I see the objects that should be there, (i.e. no tables).

Comment: not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you might have to change the display settings of your modules using perms „void showTables (bool)“ and “void tableContents (bool)”

Answer (score 0):

In the [DOORS 9.6.1 DXL Reference Manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYQBZ_9.6.1/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/dxl_reference_manual.pdf) you can see that:

> for object in document
>
> Assigns the variable o to be each successive
>   object in module. **It is equivalent to the for object in module loop,**
>   **except that it includes table header objects**, but not the row header
>   objects nor cells.

So, you must either use **for object in module** or, within your existing loop, test the hidden attribute **TableType** - this will be set to **TableNone** for anything that is not part of a table, table headers included.